# how to plot 90% confidence bands with locfit in R

Tags: r, statistics

Cross-posted from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16811/how-to-plot-90-confidence-bands-with-locfit-in-r.

I use the locfit package for some local logistic regression in R, and its scb function to plot simultaneous confidence bands. However, I see no way to request 90% confidence bands instead of the standard 95% ones. I checked the functions themselves, but I do not see where one could hack those either.

Why is there this limitation? What can one do about this?

My code goes along these lines:

```
fit2<-scb(closed_rule ~ bl,deg=1,type=4,xlim=c(0,1),ev=lfgrid(100), family='binomial',data=data,alpha=cbind(0,0.3))
```

Comment: I only glanced at the `scb` code, but it appears that 95% CIs are simply the only option the authors wrote into the function. Why? Probably because that didn't seem like an important bit of functionality to them. You options? Write it yourself or use a different local regression tool, probably.

Comment: @joran: I understand. Though even from the source of the function itself, it is not clear to me what needs to be changed to get there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The means by which you can specify CI's is a bit odd, but it can be done easily once you know how.

See the function `crit<-`, whose help page illustrates it's usage with this example.

```
library(locfit)
data(ethanol)
fit <- locfit(NOx~E,data=ethanol)
crit(fit) <- crit(fit,cov=0.99)
plot(fit,band="local")
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh, this does sound much better than what I had so far (a naive application of crit() to an scb object crashed R). Still, I don't see whether this is supposed to work for scb. That is not a single locfit object. And as I peeked into its source, it's not that easy to locate the locfit call either that I might try to hack. What is there to do?

Comment: Hi László.  Looks like it was more complicated than I thought.  `scb()` with a formula calls `locfit()`, which in turn calls `locfit.raw()` (as default value for its `lfproc=` argument.  In `locfit.raw()` the key calculations are performed by a compiled C function ( `.C("slocfit", ...)`, with the lower and upper bounds returned via `Z$L`.  So (without digging any deeper), it looks like you might need to alter the C code to get a different CIs (in this package). Best of luck!